# Forward kinematics data modeling

Tags: python, data-modeling, forward, kinematics

I have built a simple robotic arm using 3 RC Servos and an Arduino.
I just want to play around with it and learn something about robotics.

Currently, I am trying to compute the position of the tip of the robotic arm using the three angular positions of the servos.
"Forward kinematics" I think is the technical term for this. 
Btw the tip of the arm is a pen, I thought I might try to draw something with it later on.

In the movement range of the arm I set up a Cartesian coordinate system and recorded 24 (angle => position) samples.
pastebin.com/ESqWzJJB

Now, I am trying to model this data, but I am a bit out of my depth here.
Here is my approach so far:

I use the Denavit–Hartenberg equations found on Wikipedia en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denavit–Hartenberg_parameters.
I then try to determine the parameters using least squares optimization.

```
minimize(sum(norm(f(x,P)-y)^2))
```

I also added linear terms to the input and output of the model to compensate for possible distortions (e.g. phase-shift in the servo angle):

```
y = f(ax+b)*c+d
```

My Python code: pastebin.com/gQF72mQn

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Denavit-Hartenberg Matrix as found on Wikipedia "Denavit-Hartenberg parameters"
def DenHarMat(theta, alpha, a, d):
    cos_theta = cos(theta)
    sin_theta = sin(theta)
    cos_alpha = cos(alpha)
    sin_alpha = sin(alpha)


    return array([
        [cos_theta, -sin_theta*cos_alpha, sin_theta*sin_alpha, a*cos_theta],
        [sin_theta, cos_theta*cos_alpha, -cos_theta*sin_alpha, a*sin_theta],
        [0, sin_alpha, cos_alpha, d],
        [0, 0, 0, 1],
    ])


def model_function(parameters, x):
    # split parameter vector
    scale_input, parameters = split(parameters,[3])
    translate_input, parameters = split(parameters,[3])

    scale_output, parameters = split(parameters,[3])
    translate_output, parameters = split(parameters,[3])

    p_T1, parameters = split(parameters,[3])
    p_T2, parameters = split(parameters,[3])
    p_T3, parameters = split(parameters,[3])

    # compute linear input distortions
    theta = x * scale_input + translate_input

    # load Denavit-Hartenberg Matricies
    T1 = DenHarMat(theta[0], p_T1[0], p_T1[1], p_T1[2])
    T2 = DenHarMat(theta[1], p_T2[0], p_T2[1], p_T2[2])
    T3 = DenHarMat(theta[2], p_T3[0], p_T3[1], p_T3[2])

    # compute joint transformations
    # y = T1 * T2 * T3 * [0 0 0 1]
    y = dot(T1,dot(T2,dot(T3,array([0,0,0,1]))))

    # compute linear output distortions
    return y[0:3] * scale_output + translate_output


# least squares cost function
def cost_function(parameters, X, Y):
    return sum(sum(square(model_function(parameters, X[i]) - Y[i])) for i in range(X.shape[0])) / X.shape[0]


# ========== main script start ===========

# load data
data = genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='float32')
X = data[:,0:3]
Y = data[:,3:6]


cost = 9999999

#try:
#   parameters = genfromtxt('parameters.txt', delimiter=',', dtype='float32')
#   cost = cost_function(parameters, X, Y)
#except IOError:
#   pass


# random init
for i in range(100):
    tmpParams = (random.rand(7*3)*2-1)*8
    tmpCost = cost_function(tmpParams, X, Y)
    if tmpCost < cost:
        cost = tmpCost
        parameters = tmpParams
        print('Random Cost: ' + str(cost))
        savetxt('parameters.txt', parameters, delimiter=',')


# optimization
continueOptimization = True
while continueOptimization:
    res = minimize(cost_function, parameters, args=(X,Y), method='nelder-mead', options={'maxiter':100,'xtol': 1e-5})
    parameters = res.x
    print(res.fun)
    savetxt('parameters.txt', parameters, delimiter=',')
    continueOptimization = not res.success


print(res)
```

But it just won't work, none of my attempts have converged on a good solution.
I also tried a simple 3x4 matrix multiplication, which  does not make much sense as a model, but oddly it didn't do worse than the more sophisticated model above.

I hope there is someone out there who can help.

Comment: Can you please post your code in your question rather than make people go to another website to see it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to solve the inverse kinematics (IK) of your robot arm. Forward kinematics (FK) is about figuring out where your end-effector is located given the joint angles. You want to find the angles that makes the end-effector reach the desired position.

In order to solve the IK problem you have to figure out the forward-kinematics of your arm.
If you are unsure about your current FK, you could use the following script to get the symbolic FK matrices for each joint (including end-effector). It also generates the Jacobian.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *

def pos(matrix):
list = [0,0,0]
list[0] = matrix[0,3]
list[1] = matrix[1,3]
list[2] = matrix[2,3]
return np.array(list).astype(float).tolist()

class KinematicChain:

 def __init__(self):
     self.i = 1
     self.syms = []
     self.types = []
     self.matrices = []
     self.fk = []

 def add(self, type, relPos):
     """
     Parameters:
         type - the type of joint
         relpos - the position of the joint relative to the previos one
     """
     mat = self.transMatrix(type, relPos);
     self.matrices.append(mat)
     self.types.append(type)
     if len(self.fk) == 0:
         self.fk.append(eye(4)*mat)
     else:
         self.fk.append(simplify(self.fk[-1]*mat))


 def jacobian(self):
     fk = self.fk[-1]

     px = fk[0,3]
     py = fk[1,3]
     pz = fk[2,3]

     f =  Matrix([px, py, pz])

     if (len(self.syms) < 1):
         return eye(4)
     else:
         x = Matrix(self.syms)
         ans = f.jacobian(x)
         return ans



 def transMatrix(self, type, p):
     if (type != "FIXED"):
         s1 = "a" + str(self.i)
         self.i += 1
         a = symbols(s1)
         self.syms.append(a)

     if (type == "FIXED"):
         return Matrix([
         [1, 0, 0, p[0]],
         [0, 1, 0, p[1]],
         [0, 0, 1, p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "RX"):
         return Matrix([
         [1, 0, 0, p[0]],
         [0, cos(a), -sin(a), p[1]],
         [0, sin(a), cos(a), p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "RY"):
         return Matrix([
         [cos(a), 0, sin(a), p[0]],
         [0, 1, 0, p[1]],
         [-sin(a), 0, cos(a), p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "RZ"):
         return Matrix([
         [cos(a), -sin(a), 0, p[0]],
         [sin(a), cos(a), 0, p[1]],
         [0, 0, 1, p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "PX"):
         return Matrix([
         [1, 0, 0, p[0] + a],
         [0, 1, 0, p[1]],
         [0, 0, 1, p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "PY"):
         return Matrix([
         [1, 0, 0, p[0]],
         [0, 1, 0, p[1] + a],
         [0, 0, 1, p[2]],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     elif (type == "PZ"):
         return Matrix([
         [1, 0, 0, p[0]],
         [0, 1, 0, p[1]],
         [0, 0, 1, p[2] + a],
         [0, 0, 0, 1]])
     else:
         return eye(4)
```

There are many ways of solving the IK. A good one is the Damped Least Squared method. 
See: http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/ikmethods/iksurvey.pdf

A simpler method is Cyclic Coordinate Decent which is quite manageable to get working on a arduino with limited matrix support. See: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15464-s13/assignments/assignment2/jlander_gamedev_nov98.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is some kind of "kinematics calibration": identifying the robot parameters from a set of measurement data. There are numerous classic text books discussing this topic if you really want to dig deeper, for example [[Mooring et al.] "Fundamentals of manipulator calibration"](http://faculty.eng.fau.edu/rothz/files/2010/11/FUNDAMENTALS-OF-MANIPULATOR-CALIBRATION.pdf).

Back to your question, a lot of things can cause your parameter identification to fail converging, so mind you this is not a cookbook answer. ;)

One possible case is you have two (or more) joints with parallel axes. It is quite common to have this kind of configuration in simpler robots, for instance in `SCARA`, or `PUMA`-like mechanisms. In this case, with DH convention there are infinitely many way to choose the axis lines.

There are different approaches to cope with this, but YMMV. One thing that you can try is to use *Hayati-modified DH model*. This model adds one more parameter "beta" to the basic DH, to cope with singularity in parallel-axis case.

Or you can try creating your own "custom" transformation matrices to model your mechanism. For example, you can use roll-pitch-yaw (or Euler angles) to represent the rotation between joint axes, then add one length parameter to reach the next joint, etc.

Another thing that caught my attention is the _scale_output_. I think this means you can have multiple "arm length" solutions for a given data set. As an illustration, both `[scale_output=1, arm_length=100]` and `[scale_output=100, arm_length=1]` will give the same position with same joint angles. Try removing the `scale_output` from the model, and see if that helps.

Also you might want to try other optimization/minimization routines. I successfully used `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` for kinematics calibration in the past.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your goal is to learn more about robotics, building strong fundamentals first will greatly assist you in the long run. You'll most likely want to dive into the world of transformation matrices first so you'll have something to build off of when you get to more complex topics like DH-tables and inverse kinematics.

Here are some videos that may help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYQpeKYCfGs&list=PLJtm2YNbaY4_rQApwht0ia5r_sx3vaSxv